# How to change seekbar progress Position by changing value in the EditText?

Tags: android, seekbar

```
  I want to change the seekbar progress position by changing the value in EditText dynamically. please help me out from this issue .

         <EditText  
                android:id="@+id/editText1"   
                android:layout_width="120dp"   
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />    

     <SeekBar  
     android:id="@+id/seekBar1"  
     android:layout_width="match_parent"  
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"    
     android:max="4990000"    
     android:progress="10"  />
```

And here is the java code

```
    seekbar1 = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar1);
    seekbar1.setProgress(30);
    seekbar1.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
    {
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser)
        {
            spinnervalue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);

                spinnervalue.setText(""+Integer.toString(progress));

            //  Notify that the progress level has changed.  

            if(txtAmount.getText().length() > 0
                    && txtYears.getText().length() > 0
                    && txtRate.getText().length() > 0)
            {
                calculate();
            }

        }

    });
```

so by changing the values in the edittext based on the value entered in that the seekbar has to be moved to particular value.

Answer (score 4):

Try
`setProgress(Value)` of `SeekBar`.
It should be in range of value supported by your Seekbar.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !@Deepchand But Actually i want to set progressvalue to the value entered in the edittext dynamically it has to change automatically.

Comment: What I got is you need to update seek bar progress as on value is entered in EditText.
Use Edittext change watcher and in callback methods set progress in seek bar.

Comment: yeah ofcourse your correct i used the TextWatcher and here is the code

Comment: this.txtAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
  
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)  
   { 
    try { calculate(); } 
    catch (NumberFormatException nfe){ }
   }
   
  }); 
help me @Deepchand by changing edittext value the seekbar has to move repective  value.

Comment: use spinnervalue.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {});

Answer (score 1):

I think you have 2 solutions for this:

1. Create a button on the form and use the `android:onClick` in xml for this. Inside it's event you can set the Seekbar's progress by using `seekbar1.setProgress(progress);`.
2. Add a Timer and see periodically if the value has changed:

   Timer timer = new Timer();

   > ```
   >     timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
   >       @Override
   >       public void run() {
   >           runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
   >               @Override
   >               public void run() {
   >                   seekbar1.setProgress(progress);
   >               }
   >           }
   >       }
   >     }, 1000, 1000);
   > ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @user2055438 for answer ! But it has to change seekbar not by timer or by button it has to change seekbar position only when we change the value in the edittext and based on that value ie.  seekbar1.setProgress(Edittext value);

Comment: Ok then the timer one works with an addition of using `Edittext e =  (Edittext) findViewById(R.id.nameOfEditText); progress = Long.valueOf(e.getText());` Don't forget to surround with try / catch to catch NumberFormatException

Comment: This will check the value in every 1 sec so it's not so bad

Comment: yeah  @user2055438   i tried the timer code but its showing forcibly closing error but thaks for suggestion it is also one of the method to use changing the value in seekbar position but not working .

Comment: seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener( new OnSeekBarChangeListener()
  {
   public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser)
   {
    spinnervalue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);  
    spinnervalue.setText("$"+""+(progress+10000));
   }
  });

  this.txtAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count)  
   {
    try{calculate();}//Here method is used for calculating
    catch (Exception nfe) { }
   }
  });   here is the code for the seekbar i'm using @EMarci15

Comment: 02-19 10:25:24.935: W/KeyCharacterMap(291): No keyboard for id 0
02-19 10:25:24.935: W/KeyCharacterMap(291): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
02-19 10:25:26.457: D/dalvikvm(185): GREF has increased to 201
02-19 10:25:28.866: D/dalvikvm(291): GC_CONCURRENT freed 260K, 51% free 2950K/5959K, external 989K/1038K, paused 6ms+20ms  02-19 10:24:58.156: I/ActivityManager(60): Displayed com.android.email/.activity.MessageCompose: +1s673ms (total +2s144ms)
@EMarci15

Comment: Into the {} after the catch part insert `nfe.printStackTrace()` to insert the exception into the Logcat. also think about the cases of the text is empty/not a number/is null. these can cause exceptions

Answer (score 0):

As much I got to know regarding your situation. You have 1 `EditText` & 1 `SeekBar` & on text change in EditText you want to set the SeekBar current selected position.

So to achieve this you need to use an `onTextChangedListener` on `EditText` and do the following in it.

First define
`spinnervalue=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
 spinnervalue.setOnTextChangeListener(this)` in `onCreate()`

now use following code in `onTextChanged`

```
String value = spinnervalue.getText().toString();
try{
    int progress = Integer.parseInt(value);
    if (progress >= 0 && progress <= 100)
        {
          Log.e("", "Value set:" + progress);
          seekbar1.setProgress(progress);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.e("", "Value set:" + value);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }    
}
```

also do add the below code to **seekbar-tag** in layout

```
android:max="100"
```

Hope I am understandable.

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @harpreet for ur suggestion ! But i want edittext value to be entered in that automatically by changing the value in it.

Comment: @Danny Please check the answer again.

Comment: yeah i implemented it but the seekbar position is not moving by changing the edittext value @Harpreet

Comment: Have you checked what value is it getting using Log.?

Comment: 02-19 10:25:24.935: W/KeyCharacterMap(291): No keyboard for id 0 02-19 10:25:24.935: W/KeyCharacterMap(291): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin 02-19 10:25:26.457: D/dalvikvm(185): GREF has increased to 201 02-19 10:25:28.866: D/dalvikvm(291): GC_CONCURRENT freed 260K, 51% free 2950K/5959K, external 989K/1038K, paused 6ms+20ms 02-19 10:24:58.156: I/ActivityManager(60): Displayed com.android.email/.activity.MessageCompose: +1s673ms (total +2s144ms) @Harpreet

Comment: 02-20 12:24:24.485: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 12:24:24.485: E/AndroidRuntime(440): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 12:24:24.485: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at com.AppDevelopment.mortgagecalculator.Mortgagecalc.onCreate(Mortgagecalc.java:43)
02-20 12:24:24.485: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
02-20 12:24:24.485: E/AndroidRuntime(440):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611) @Harpreet

Comment: this is the code i appended with ur code like this @Harpreet                              txtAmount = (EditText)  findViewById(R.id.editText1);  this.txtAmount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
   public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,    int count)  
{
 String value = txtAmount.getText().toString();
 try{
  int progress = Integer.parseInt(value);
  if (progress >= 0 && progress <= 1990)
  {
   Log.e("", "Value set:" + progress);
   seekbar.setProgress(progress);
  }
 }
 catch(Exception e)
 {
  Log.e("", "Value set:" + value);
  e.printStackTrace();
 }